# creating xml using xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I am creating an xml document using xsd. When the xml got created the encoding value is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?>
```

what i required is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Here is my xsd.

```
<xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="shipto">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                        <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger" />
                        <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="orderid" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Can any please let me know why this is happening.

Comment: What did you use to make the XML?

Comment: According to the link below, schema does not dictate the encoding:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412343/can-xsd-schema-validate-encoding-e-g-utf-8-possible

Comment: am using Benerator, and the command is                            createXML.bat transactions.xsd shiporder tx-{0}.xml 2

Comment: As both encoding="WINDOWS-1252" and encoding="utf-8" are single byte encoding the code will work.
Bautista : Link was informative, Thank U